# Abstract class saying it is not found

Tags: php, laravel, abstract-class

I am trying to use an abstract class for the following and I am getting an error saying:

> Class 'Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer' does not exist.

I also Added the controller class in case there may be something wrong with that. Can anyone let me know what I am overlooking here?

### LessonTransformer

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Transformers;

class LessonTransformer extends Transformer {

    public function transform($lesson){

        return [

            'title'=> $lesson['title'],

            'body' => $lesson['body'],

            'active' => (boolean) $lesson['some_bool']

        ];
    }
}
```

### Transformer

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Transformers;

abstract class Transformer{

    public function transformCollection($items){

        return array_map([$this, 'transform'], $items);

    }

    abstract public function transform($item);
}
```

### LessonsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;
use App\Lesson as Lesson;

class LessonsController extends Controller
{

    protected $lessonTransformer;

    function __construct(LessonTransformer $lessonTransformer){

        $this->lessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;

    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // 1. All is bad
        // 2. No way to attach meta data
        // 3. Linking the Db structure to api output
        // 4. No way to signal headers or response codes
        // return Lesson::all();

        $lessons = Lesson::all();
        return response()->json([
            'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transformCollection($lessons->all())
        ], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $lesson = Lesson::find($id);

        if(!$lesson){
            return response()->json([

            'error' => [
                'message' => 'lesson does not exist'
            ]

            ], 404);
        }

        return response()->json([

            'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transform($lesson)

        ],200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

### composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.7",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories",
            "app/acme"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: __How__ do you use your classes?

Comment: Share the composer.json (at least require: {} part, and the filenames of the two files above)

Comment: The error is not generated on any of the lines you included as example code. Show us the line of code that generates the error.

Comment: The error appears to be saying the inheriting class `LessonTransformer` cannot be found, not the abstract class. I assume that the filename and path are correct according to your autoloader config? And case may or may not be relevant, depending on the environment that is running your code.

Comment: just added the controller class, i will add the composer.json now.

Comment: Import is `use App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;` but the classes are defined under `Acme\Transformers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't this

```
use App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;
```

be this

```
use Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;
```

??

Comment: That was exactly the issue, I must've just been overlooking this! thank you so much

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your transformer classes under the following namespace:

```
namespace Acme\Transformers;
```

But you are importing `LessonTransformer` under:

```
use App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer
```

Which is a different namespace. So you need to amend that to:

```
use Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer
```

Comment: That was the issue, I must've just been overlooking it, Thank you so much!